# Plot 3D line bars, i. e. lines with a plane reaching to zero

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

In a `plot3` (or with any other function) is it somehow possible to the let lines have a plane below them, a plane which is limited by the line an the x-y plane?

This might give an idea:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation to `fill3()`? THis returns you a filled area which if you define it with constant x or y should give you a plane

Answer (score 1):

You can try plotting the planes as [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) objects (polygons). This way you can play around with their transparency, color and so on.

There are some interesting things you can do with patches (and related functions): [FEX: 3d-array plotting with patch](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28497-plot-a-3d-array-using-patch), [`fill3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `fill3` [(doc)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) for this as in

```
fill3( [x fliplr(x)] , [y fliplr(y)] , [z 0 0] , RGB_triplet)
```

where the 3-D line is defined by the (x,y,z) coordinates of the end of the line segment. The plane is then defined by adding 2 more coordinates: `fliplr` for `x` and `y` (left/right flip of the end points) and [0 0] for `z`.

The following code

```
x = [1 4]
y = [3 2]
z = [5 0]

figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
plot3(x,y,z)
grid on
subplot(1,2,2)
fill3([x fliplr(x)],[y fliplr(y)],[z 0 0],[0.3 0.5 0.7])
grid on
```

produces

[image]